# how do I repeat an image in java script using a for loop so that the picture is printed multiple times in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a little sailboat with a drawing of the moon and the sun. How would I create a for loop so that the sailboat, moon and the sun all are repeated across the x and y axis's without repeating the same instructions over and over. The code I made doesn't run when I save it and open the file.

```
for(var x = 0; x <= 600; x+200) 
                {
                    for(var y = 0; y <= 600; y+200)
                    {
                            drawWholeBoat(ctx, 200, 300); 
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What goes wrong? (Also you should use `let` not `var` in your for loops). [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: You need to say `x = x + 200` or `x += 200` (same modification for `y`), since currently this is an infinite loop because `x` and `y` are never changing. You should also say `drawWholeBoat(ctx, x, y)` since thats the point of having x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this code, check comments for details:

```js
for (let x = 0; x <= 600; x += 200) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= 600; y += 200) {
      drawWholeBoat(ctx, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Fixed up the problem immediately.

Comment: this is an awful way of doing this.  Try the following: body {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/50");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

Comment: @DCR they're using a canvas, not trying to set the background of the whole page